# Sustainsys.Saml2 v2.4.0 with Chrome version 81 and samesite cookies not working

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

Right now I am testing our web application for compatibility with the upcoming Chrome changes.

For this we updated Sustainsys.Saml2.Owinto the 2.4.0 version.
Testing with the new Chrome developer version shows 2 cookies are being set:
- A cookie One with secure and HttpOnly, but no SameSite
- The same cookie with secure and HttpOnly and SameSite=None

This looks correct, yet when I check in Chrome, it still gives me the warning that SameSite was not set to none and will be treated as lax, the login result is sent to the Acs page.

And if I wait more than 2 minutes on the login screen, the login will fail because it will miss the cookie on the Acs page. 
So the only reason it is working now, it the grace period that Chrome has set.

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Do you run Kentor.OwinCookieSaver in this application? Have you implemented a SameSiteCookieManager/SystemWebCookieManager? What are the names of the Cookies?

Comment: Yes, we do use KentorOwinCookieSaver.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate cookie is caused by the Kentor.OwinCookieSaver package. Remove it and make sure to implement the SystemWebCookieManager instead. The SystemWebCookieManager was not available when I published the OwinCookieSaver, but now it is and it is a much better solution.

Comment: That did solve the issue. Now it all works as expected. Thank you for your time